# How do I get my HTC Desire out of the boot loop?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, recovery-mode, data-recovery, boot-loop

I just screwed up my HTC Desire. I had some low memory issues so I decided to power it off. I then went into 'recovery', and then 'mounts and storage', and then 'mount /sd-ext'. At this point it went all black, I guess in order to mount it, and showed me the menu again. I remember that an 'unmount' option appeared. I think I did 'mount /sdcard' then. I then chose reboot system now.

Since I did this, there is the HTC Quietly Brilliant white splash screen appearing and the phone is booting, I hear the HTC signature boot up melody, and then it starts to loop at this point. It doesn't stop until I pull out the battery.

The phone is rooted, s-offed, has stock ROM with Sense, and AlphaRev Recovery.

What should I do to make it boot again? I don't want to do any formatting or data wipes. I have unsaved personal data. I don't have a fresh backup.

**Update:**

I have managed to boot it now. I used both options in CWM recovery to wipe both regular "cache" and Dalvik cache. And then I chose to rebooted. It took very long time to boot.

I am presented with following problems now.

1. There is this message saying

   > Not enough storage space for SMS/MMS
   >
   > Your phone's storage is almost full. You...
2. Crash

   > The application Google Services Framework has stopped working
   >   (process com.google.process.gapps) has stopped unexpectedly. Please
   >   try again.
3. Crash

   > The application Facebook (process com.facebook.katana) has stopped
   >   unexpectedly. Please try again.
4. Low on space

   > Phone storage space is getting low.
5. Missing apps! Google apps are apparently not available. I think this has to do with that Services Framework thing crashing. There were some other apps crashing as well, I think they were just some minor apps, I didn't catch on to note them down, apps were crashing like on a production line.

The reason why so many apps are missing I think is because I used an app called Link2SD which makes symbolic links for Dalvik cache, libraries and for the APK of apps. It moves these to the SD card, and tricks the system into thinking that they are present on the internal memory. I don't see the Link2SD app icon any more. Can I recover these somehow?...

Where do I go from here? Do I rescue what I can, or do I try to fix the problem? Essentially, do I save myself or do I extinguish the fire?

**Update:**

I had to manually install Play Store using ADB from the computer. I used it to download and install the missing apps I needed to backup the most important data. I then flashed a new custom ROM on the phone.

Comment: I've just added the `boot-loop` tag to your question (as you describe that as being your problem). You might want to check the [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) for some first-aid information, and also take a look at its [most frequented questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot-loop?sort=frequent).

Comment: I will do that, thanks. Is there a non-destructive way to recover from a boot loop? Most of the methods I have reviewed online involve either flashing or performing a factory restore, and clearing/wiping cache and user data.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this is a boot loop problem at all. Like I said, it started as a memory issue. Most HTC devices I have seen on YouTube that are stuck in boot loop start to loop as soon as the HTC logo appears. On my device I can see the "Quietly Brilliant" animation and hear the start up melody. So I'm thinking it maybe fails to mount /system or /data. Is there a way I can clear this out a little bit, manually, so it's not low on memory?

Comment: What is a "force-close-loop" as mentioned in the linked page?

Comment: non-destructive: wiping cache, wiping dalvik-cache. Dalvik-Cache will be rebuilt at the next startup (it's just optimized code of the apps installed), and cache either holds temporary files only. Boot-Loop: If it *loops* instead of simply getting stuck, i.e. the boot-process repeats. Force-Close-Loop: an app starts, crashes with a "unfortunately..has stopped", gets force-closed, and all that starts over in a loop.

Comment: How do I know when the phone is in safe mode? I assume this is not the same thing as the HBOOT menu? On HTC website they say that for my specific phone I should power it off, then "briefly press the Power button to turn on the phone" and "while the phone powers on, press and hold the Volume down button until the phone loads the OS". What happens is the white HTC screen stays for a little longer without starting to loop, then goes a little darker (reads my brightness settings), but then starts looping again.

Comment: I have the "Why so serious" with Joker logo when I enter recovery. It's custom recovery by AlphaRev, version 2.5.1.8 based on CWM (clockwork mod). Can I use this to make a backup of my contacts, messages, calendar, app data, etc? Maybe a full blown image backup?

Comment: There is an option called 'wipe cache partition' and also under 'advanced' there is 'wipe dalvik cache' option. Can I use either one to wipe cache data?

Comment: Sammy, a few things: this is not a discussion forum here, so we handle things a little different. For one: only one question per post. Number two: Answers are answers. So may I ask you to move your solution for the boot loop to an answer (which you then should "accept" after the 2-day forced delay), and open new questions for the other problems? Thank you! -- For safe-mode, see the [safe-mode tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info) please. And the cache options are for app-cache resp. Dalvik-cache, both are safe to use without data loss.